# Where is the local cached version of a streamed video?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-media-player, cache, video-streaming

I had opened a video website and watched a streamed video which has been completely buffered. I want to get a copy of the video, which I know is located somewhere in my hard-disk because it's completely cached. how do i find its location? This is how i played it.

```
1. Opened Windows media player
2. Selected "Open URL" from the File menu.
3. Pasted the URL and played the video.
```

It took some 2 hrs to have it completely buffered and watchable. I just want to get the cached copy of it from my hard-disk.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning that caching implies a useful representation on disk is flawed, though not necessarily incorrect.

However, I suggest you open the file in some more capable media software with native file output support. Both [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) and [vlc](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/) could likely be used, provided you're not stopped by some provider restriction.